# Why does my error my exceptions handling cause an infinite loop?

Tags: java, exception

I'm having trouble with my exception handling. The program runs fine if I input a number but create an infinite loop if a character is entered.

```
boolean ask= true;
    while(ask)
    {
        ask = false;
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("What is the age?");
            int age = input.nextInt();  
            setAge(age);
        }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            ask = true;
        }
    }//end while
```

Comment: Because `Scanner.nextInt()` will only consume an `int`. If there isn't one, it throws an exception - and doesn't consume the thing that isn't an `int`. Add a `input.nextLine();` in your `catch` block.

Comment: Regarding your comment: the scanner can't give you individual chars. It reads all input until you press enter.

Comment: @GhostCat I meant a character or a String. My bad on the misunderstanding.

Comment: Then you have to read strings, not int values. If at all, you can only get all these chars together within a string!

Comment: @GhostCat I don't want to read in a char or String. I'm trying to get the user to return an age (int)

Comment: I know what you want. I am telling you what is possible. And hint: the scanner only reads strings. If you ask for an int, it is parsing that string for you. When you ask the scanner for the underlying string, your own code is in control, and you can do things slightly differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
      boolean ask= false;
        while(!ask)
        {
           try
           {
               System.out.println("What is the age?");
               int age = input.nextInt();//does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting "Enter,"
               setAge(age);
               ask = true;
           }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Invalid input!");
               input.nextLine();//consumes the \n character
           }
        }//end while
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you enter "abc"

Your call to `input.nextInt()` causes the scanner to look at the `a` and say "That's not an int, so I will throw an exception."

In the exception handler, you set `ask` to `true` so the loop repeats.

When the loop repeats, the scanner looks at that exact same `a` again, and it says "That's not an int, so I will throw an exception."

In the exception handler, you set `ask` to `true` so the loop repeats.

And so on....

That pesky `a` never gets consumed by the scanner.

Comment: I see what you're saying. My thought is that it would loop again to see if the user input is a character, and then **pause** to ask for another user input if it was instead of an infinite loop.

Comment: That's a totally understandable assumption! It's just that unfortunately things don't work that way with `nextInt()`. Other ways of reading input exist where you actually read in a whole line, say, and then check if that's an integer or not, and then try again by reading the _next_ line. (Python's `readline()` works like that, as to Java's input streams and readers.) It's just that `Scanner` behaves differently. Totally makes sense that you would assume the pause, which would indeed happen in `nextInt()` actually consumed any input, but alas, it just doesn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of nextInt:

```
    public int nextInt(int radix) {
        // Check cached result
        if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Integer)
            && this.radix == radix) {
            int val = ((Integer)typeCache).intValue();
            useTypeCache();
            return val;
        }
        setRadix(radix);
        clearCaches();
        // Search for next int
        try {
            String s = next(integerPattern());
            if (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null)
                s = processIntegerToken(s);
            return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
            throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

It uses `Integer.parseInt(s, radix);` to produce the result.
If call `Integer.parseInt("s");` will result:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s"